# installing pip3 on ubuntu 12.04 docker image

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

I am trying to install and install pip3 on docker image. The initial configuration used is

`FROM ubuntu:12.04
MAINTAINER Candidate @ Ctx  <candidate@caltex.com.au>
LABEL "name"="Troubleshooting Test" 
USER root
ENV PY_DIR /home/dev`

After refering to some posts(https://askubuntu.com/questions/412178/how-to-install-pip-for-python-3-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts) about this I am following below steps:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    build-essential \ 
    python3-setuptools \
    python-dev 

RUN easy_install3 pip
```

The output is abrupt and contains :

```
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pip/_vendor/progress/spinner.py", line 32
    phases = [u'\u25f7', u'\u25f6', u'\u25f5', u'\u25f4']
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also when I use pip3 it has similar issue. I have tried to install it with command : `apt-get install python3-pip`

But that also doesn't works. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: `ubuntu:12.04` is already out of support. So why don't you use `14.04` or `16.04`

Comment: I am using it as a part of requirement so don't have real control on choosing ubuntu version

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to install latest version of pip on a unsupported python version. Available version are

> versions: 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 9.0.0, 9.0.1

Solution is to use the version with works

```
RUN easy_install3 pip==7.1.2
```

From `8.0.0` you may see the issue that you are facing now